# I have to be crass about it

Tags: sentence-meaning

This is a sentence as heading I came across in a video which she was talking about her attitude to the Trump's Tweet tirade After I looked crass up in dictionaries, I still confused about the meaning of the whole sentence. I am not sure what implication the speaking people want to convey, as crass I've got is like an synonym of insensitive. Does she not want to continue focusing on this related news? I posted the whole script she said below.

> My issue with this president, who I voted for, is the fact that he has something negative to say about every other leader. But you try saying one little comment that's negative about Trump himself, he jumps into a fit, and he has this Twitter tirade. You know, we have a lot of really -- I mean, ***I have to be crass about it***, idiots who voted for him, including myself at one time

Answer (score 2):

to be crass here means to be blunt in an almost vulgar manner.

It would be crass of him to say this is a stupid question. [for example]

Comment: I am not sure whether I've understood is right. If I have to say something offensive to others but it is worth saying it at least in my mind, in this context, I can use this sentence right before my a little rude speech?

Comment: @Young Exactly, that's it.